How to read multiple parquet files from a gcp storage bucket using duckdb and python

python version: Python 3.12.3
duckdb version: "1.1.3"

I'm trying to get duckdb working to read multiple parquet files from a storage bucket dir using a glob pattern.
I can load a single file using the following:
# works
duckdb.register_filesystem(filesystem("gcs"))
test_file = "gcs:///some_bucket/some_dir/some_file.parquet"
data = duckdb.sql(f"SELECT * FROM read_parquet('{test_file}')")

Based on https://duckdb.org/docs/data/multiple_files/overview.html I expect to be able to use the following, but it fails:
# fail
duckdb.register_filesystem(filesystem("gcs"))
test_file = "gcs:///some_bucket/some_dir/*.parquet"
data = duckdb.sql(f"SELECT * FROM read_parquet('{test_file}')")

With the error:
duckdb.duckdb.IOException: IO Error: No files found that match the pattern "gcs:///some_bucket/some_dir/*.parquet"

I know that there is a parquet file which would match that glob though, based on the initial (working) version which explicitly states the file to query.
Loading multiple via a list
Note, when I tried the following:
 a = "gs://some_bucket/some_dir/a.parquet"
 b = "gs://some_bucket/some_dir/b.parquet"
 data = duckdb.sql(f"SELECT * FROM read_parquet(['{a}', '{b}'], union_by_name=true)")

It works, though I'm not sure if this is relevant to my initial issue re globs or not.
Edit: ListObjectV2 required for file glob
Following answer:
> The documentation for the httpfs extension implies that globbing is only supported for s3. See https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/httpfs/overview.html
I was confused as (to me) the docs here: https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/httpfs/s3api seemed to imply that google storage was also supported, looking again (at  https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/httpfs/s3api ) it states:
File glob   ListObjectV2

Searching for support on this brings up:

(7 years old) Is the ListObjectsV2 api call implemented in Google Cloud Storage? and the
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155109631

At the end of the https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155109631 thread there's a link to: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/release-notes#July_1k2_2021 which states:
List object V2 for the XML APIPreview launched.

List object V2 provides improved interoperability with Amazon S3 tools and libraries.

I don't know enough about this to know if that's what duckdb needs.

The documentation for the httpfs extension implies that globbing is only supported for s3. See https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/httpfs/overview.html

thanks - i'm a bit confused as following those links seems to suggest that GCP implements the s3 api and has the ListObjectsv2 required for glob? I've updated the original post with some links / context on that though, thanks

I’d suggest making an ER at https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues.  That way you’ll at least get clarity. And perhaps raising the issue will make someone realize it would be easy to support?
